# How to order data without the name title?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have some problem. I want to order the data base on their name. But some of the data got Mr, Prof on the first name. Example :

### Name

1. Mr. Bernard Ford
2. Dr. Clinton Steward
3. Alex Smith

I want the output like

1. Alex Smith
2. Mr. Bernard Ford
3. Dr. Clinton Steward

It should use WHERE statement. Anyone knows how to deal with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by 'It should use WHERE statement'

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT NAME 
from (SELECT case when  ROUND ((LENGTH(col1) - LENGTH(REPLACE( col1, " ", ""))) / LENGTH(" ")) > 1 then 
                  SUBSTRING_INDEX( col1, ' ', -2 ) 
             else 
                  col1 
             end as NAME
      from test) A
order by NAME
```

Here is a demo:

> > > [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d251ecb4e0f1aa10fbe5603eb36e539)

In my demo the table is called test, the column in that table is called col1.
If you want to show original names then:

```
SELECT Org_name 
from (SELECT case when  ROUND ((LENGTH(col1) - LENGTH(REPLACE( col1, " ", ""))) / LENGTH(" ")) > 1 then 
                  SUBSTRING_INDEX( col1, ' ', -2 ) 
             else 
                  col1 
             end as NAME
             , col1 Org_name
      from test) A
order by NAME
```

Comment: What if the full name consists from 3 parts? Or it is single? Or there is multi-space (typo, for example)? Your query will give wrong output for all these variants. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02a48897bd52ee1c734d85775862a67c PS. OP don't want to remove the title part in output, he needs in correct sorting of the rows only.

Comment: @Akina, I agrre on both comments(multispace and remove title part) Multispace: I have provided the answer for the examples OP provided. Also, in my second code you can see that I have provided a solution that shows original name... Also, if I may add, the question can be also asked what if There is no '.' in the 'Mr.' part...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY TRIM(SUBSTRING(name FROM 1 + LOCATE('.', name)))
```